# Добавить одному из одноименных элементов класс, если виден другой такой же по очереди одноименный элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="parent-box">
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>`
   <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent-pushes">
   <div class="push"></div>
   <div class="push"></div>`
   <div class="push"></div>
</div>
```

Здравствуйте. Прошу помощи в оформлении идеи. Суть в том чтобы добавить класс current к блоку с классом push. Добавить нужно к тому push, в зависимости от того какой он в списке среди таких же. Какой именно - определяется тем, какой из блоков box пересек верхнюю черту окна. То есть пересекли 3-й box - добавили класс 3-му push и т.п. Остальные блоки вне зоны видимости должны лишаться данного класса.

Мои знания в js очень малы, поэтому и прошу помощи. Все что я смог - это добавить класс current к самому блоку box, если он пересек границу окна.

```
$(document).on('scroll', function () {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('.dr-box').offset().top) { 
          $('.dr-box').addClass('current');
     } else {
          $('.dr-box').removeClass('current');
     }
    });
```

Однако добавляется он ко всем box сразу.

Я так понимаю нужно писать более сложное условие: если высота скролла окна > высоты на которой находиться box (второй по списку), то добавить класс current к этому же box и push (также второму по списку), в противном случае не добавлять класс current к данным элементам.

И еще условие чтоб классы удалялись: если высота скролла окна > суммы=(высота на которой находиться box (например первый по списку))+(высота самого блока box (этого же)) , то убирает класс current у box и push (также второму по списку) если но есть, в противном случае ничего не происходит.

По итогу: если мы чуть вверх проскроллим второй box, то у первого push и box исчезнет класс current, а у второго box и push появиться.

Я это так вижу в теории, хотя не знаю насколько это сложно реализовать ибо у самого не достаточно знаний. Возможно у вас есть более простые и рациональные решения.

По итогу должно выйти что при скролее вниз, можно будет увидеть номер блока, прописав поочередно в каждый push текст 1,2,3,4 и т.д. Каждый push будет прозрачный. А класс current заставит отображается тот или инной блок с цифрой.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Индексы элементов считаются начиная с нуля. Если у вас 3 элемента, это 0-й, 1-й и 2-й. Конкретный элемент в jQuery можно взять через `$('.класс').eq( номер )`.

`for( var i = $box.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )`

$box.length — всего 3 элемента. Но индекс последнего == 2, поэтому цикл начинается от `$box.length - 1`, заканчивается на 0, на каждом круге номер уменьшается на 1: `i--` то же, что и `i = i - 1`

`!$(this).hasClass('current')` — Логическое НЕ `!`, условие сработает только если у текущего элемента нет класса 'current'. Чтобы лишний раз не убирать-добавлять.

```js
var $box = $('.box');
var $push = $('.push');

$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  console.clear();
  console.log( "window scroll → " + $(window).scrollTop() );

  for( var i = $box.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){
    console.log( "box номер " + i + " // top → " + $box.eq(i).offset().top );
    
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > $box.eq(i).offset().top && !$(this).hasClass('current') ){
      $('.push.current').removeClass('current');
      $push.eq(i).addClass('current');
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.parent-pushes {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #123;
}

.push {
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.push.current {
  background-color: #045acf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent-box">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent-pushes">
  <div class="push">1</div>
  <div class="push">2</div>
  <div class="push">3</div>
</div>
```